# Open microsoft word document by php on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, ms-word, com

I have windows server with apache and php. I'm trying to open microsoft word document with this code:

```
<?php
 $doc  = __DIR__."\test.doc";   
 $word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object."); 
 $word->Documents->Open($doc); 
 // Extract content. 
 $content = $word->ActiveDocument->Content; 
 echo $content; 
 $word->ActiveDocument->Close(); 
?>
```

All working fine while apache is running as a Console Application. But if I'm trying to run apache as service, this code stops working.

What I did, trying to solve this problem:

1. run apache service under a normal user account
2. fill in the same user account information at dcomcnfg.exe->Console Root->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003
3. start Word again and sure no dialogs, license, etc.
4. restart apache service

But script doesn't work. In the task manager, after run script, I watch WINWORD.EXE with constantly increasing memory but nothing else happens.

After that i switch to Console Application and all is working!

How can I do this script from Apache as service? What did I miss?

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: Check the apache logs for any errors

Comment: check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php#90076